# How to get a notification whenever a user creates a MediaWiki account?

Tags: mediawiki, users, wiki, notification

I'm an administrator and bureaucrat on a few wikis. One wiki allows users to create their own account without approval. Spammers are taking advantage of it and spamming in their profiles.

I checked under preferences, and I can't find a preference related to account creation and watch lists.

***Question***: How do I subscribe to notifications when an account is created?

*Related*: though I am an administrator and bureaucrat, I don't have SSH access to the boxes, and I don't have admin on the boxes. So I can't remote in and change configurations. I'm sandboxed into the administrator interface provided to wiki administrators and bureaucrats.

Comment: I don't know the particular version of MediaWiki. The wiki in question is Crypto++'s wiki at http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ (in case you can tell by looking at it).

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki has a [Special:ListUsers page](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AListUsers&username=&group=&creationSort=1&desc=1&limit=50) that you can monitor for new users.   You need to check

- Sort by creation date
- Sort in descending order

and uncheck

- Show only users with edits  (or maybe check it to catch only the spammers who have made edits)

to get a list of the newest users.

I don't know of a built in way for it to email notifications to you without you having the ability to install extensions.  You can however, monitor the ListUsers page for changes.   I've used web  page monitoring services in the past that send emails when a web page changes and one of those might do the job for you.